# Windows container failed to start with error, "failed to create endpoint on network nat: HNS failed with error : Failed to create endpoint."

Tags: windows-server, docker-container

I have been trying Windows Containers on windows server 2016 TP5. Suddenly I started getting error while running a container with port maping option `-p 80:80`

```
c:\>docker run -it -p 80:80 microsoft/iis cmd
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint sharp_brahmagupta on network nat: HNS failed with error : Failed to create endpoint.
```

I made sure that no other container is running and port 80 on host machine is not being used by any other service.

Did anyone face same issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After searching around I stunbled upon [this](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22084) issue on github. This seemed to be a known issue with Windows containers on Windows server TP5.

Then thanks to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cd83c90c-ce58-428e-9b39-ccdafab6952e/not-able-to-start-containers-in-windows2016tp5?forum=windowscontainers) forum, I found the solution
You can check active static port mapping with below command

```
C:\>powershell
PS C:\>Get-NetNatStaticMapping


StaticMappingID               : 3
NatName                       : Hda6caca4-06ec-4251-8a98-1fe0b4c5af88
Protocol                      : TCP
RemoteExternalIPAddressPrefix : 0.0.0.0/0
ExternalIPAddress             : 0.0.0.0
ExternalPort                  : 80
InternalIPAddress             : 172.31.181.4
InternalPort                  : 80
InternalRoutingDomainId       : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Active                        : True
```

From above output it seemed that even though container was removed the static port mapping was not removed and was still active.

But I removed it with below command.

```
PS C:\> Get-NetNatStaticMapping | ? ExternalPort -eq 80 | Remove-NetNatStaticMapping
```

Then simply rebooted the system and the error was gone.

Answer (score 9):

For me these steps solved the problem:

```
Stop-Service docker
Get-ContainerNetwork | Remove-ContainerNetwork
Get-NetNat | Remove-NetNat
Get-VMSwitch | Remove-VMSwitch
Start-Service docker
```

(suggested by JMesser81 at:https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/273)

Answer (score 6):

I had similar error.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.13.0-rc3, build 4d92237
$ docker-compose -f .\docker-compose.windows.yml up
Starting musicstore_db_1

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: {"message":"failed to create endpoint musicstore_db_1 on network nat: HNS failed with error : Unspecified error"}
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Static mapping removal did not work, only network removal helped:

```
Get-ContainerNetwork -Name nat | Remove-ContainerNetwork
```

Execute the command in PowerShell as administrator, then restart Docker.

---

**Update:**

Use [CleanupContainerHostNetworking.ps1](https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/tree/live/windows-server-container-tools/CleanupContainerHostNetworking) script to resolve Docker 17 networking issues.

```
.\CleanupContainerHostNetworking.ps1 -Cleanup -ForceDeleteAllSwitches
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a docker and docker-compose which were already working on Centos.
I did the following changes to make it work on windows server 2016:

1. Stop the docker service, remove nat, start the docker service.

   ```
   ps>stop-service docker
   ps>Get-ContainerNetwork | Remove-ContainerNetwork -Force -ea SilentlyContinue
   ps>start-service docker
   ```
2. Configure network in your docker-compose.yml

   ```
   version: '3.7'
   networks:
     default:
       external:
         name: nat
   ```

That's It!