# How to Fixing “HNS failed with error : Unspecified error” on docker-compose for Windows server 2016

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose, windows-server-2016, .net-framework-version

I am using Visual studio 2017 IDE for windows dockerizing  purpose of  a Mvc app(DotNet 4.5) which depends on sql server .For that i am using Windows server 2016 datacenter, version 10.0.14393 build 14393 
 with docker(64 bit) ,it gave info as  ran "docker version" at PS

```
PS C:\Users\tutul2018> docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.03.1-ee-3
 API version:       1.37
 Go version:        go1.10.2
 Git commit:        b9a5c95
 Built:             Thu Aug 30 18:42:35 201
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.03.1-ee-3
  API version:      1.37 (minimum version 1
  Go version:       go1.10.2
  Git commit:       b9a5c95
  Built:            Thu Aug 30 18:56:49 201
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Below is docker file :-

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

Below is 'docker-compose.yml' file, here i am preparing instructions for Mvc App image and sql server image :-

```
version: '3.4'
services:

  webapplicationdockerapp-db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express
    container_name: webapplicationdockerapp-db
    environment:
      sa_password: "Test@12"
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"

  webapplicationdockerapp:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapplicationdockerapp
    build:
      context: .\WebApplicationDockerApp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      TestDB: "Server=webapplicationdockerapp-db;Database=TestDB;User Id=sa;Password=Test@12;"
    depends_on:
      - "webapplicationdockerapp-db"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Below is 'docker-compose.overrides.yml' file , here i am describing the network of default as 'nat':-

```
version: '3.4'  
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

**When i tried to run the Mvc app using container at windows server 2016 by visual studio 2017 IDE, it gave an error as "HNS failed with error : Unspecified error” .Below as**

*Recreating dockercompose10638987249071720390_webapplicationdockerapp_1 ... 
Recreating dockercompose10638987249071720390_webapplicationdockerapp_1 ... error
ERROR: for dockercompose10638987249071720390_webapplicationdockerapp_1  Cannot start service webapplicationdockerapp: failed to create endpoint dockercompose10638987249071720390_webapplicationdockerapp_1 on network nat: HNS failed with error : Unspecified error
ERROR: for webapplicationdockerapp  Cannot start service webapplicationdockerapp: failed to create endpoint dockercompose10638987249071720390_webapplicationdockerapp_1 on network nat: HNS failed with error : Unspecified error
Encountered errors while bringing up the project..*

Pls guide or help.

Thanks,

Comment: have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38070837/windows-container-failed-to-start-with-error-failed-to-create-endpoint-on-netw ?

Comment: and this: https://xebia.com/blog/fixing-hns-failed-with-error-unspecified-error-on-docker-compose-for-windows/ ?

Comment: Thanks @Sunny. I will try it out and let u update.